# libpam load pam modules at every connection

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, openssl

I want to reduce ssh connection time, by debugging sshd have found that libpam is loading all pam modules specified in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file at every connection.

How to configure/modifiy libpam such that it loads modules only for first connection and after it uses same modules for every connection? I know libpam was designed for loading pam modules but want to load pam modules once.

Let me know if anyone have any idea.

I'm using `OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0l and Linux-PAM-1.1.3`

Comment: Out of curiosity, did your debugging actually show that PAM loading was slow compared to the other parts of starting the session?  If so, is PAM doing a lot of work to do authentication or is it really just the loading that is slow?  Sorry to ask so many skeptical questions, it is just very surprising to me.  I would expect other portions of the connection to dwarf simply loading the PAM modules.  For example, if you have "UseDNS" set to yes.